# Basement rough-in. Converting plumbing from a tub to a fiberglass shower

Tags: basement, shower, drain, tub, rough-in

the basement rough-in was completed with a shower/tub rough-in.  I want to convert it to a shower.  I bought an alcove left drain fiberglass tub. The shower does have a p-trap and everything should be vented already. To install the shower drain, do I just need to cut the tub rough-in below the contract and add two 45 street elbows to where the permanent shower drain will be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I uploaded some pictures to help.  http://imgur.com/a/Xe9io

Comment: Are you asking how to shift the location of the drain pipe? It's not clear what the question is. (Please edit your title to pose a specific question as well.)

Comment: That doesn't look like a shower/bath drain.  It looks like a sink drain.  Do you have a pic of the whole bathroom.  A typical basement roughin should have 3 holes going down.

Answer (score 1):

That pipe that is pictured above the floor may be the beginning of a vent pipe. Yes it does look like there is a trap below the floor, from what I can see, a little more dirt removed would have been good, but it looks like it is there. If the tubs bottom is high enough, you will not need to remove more concrete, the drain of the tub can set above the concrete floor, most tubs do not allow that. Most likely you will need to break out about 8-12" more under the tub to set the drain. Typically the trap is glued in last so the pipe from the overflow and tub drain is a straight shot down into the J bend of the trap. With the way it is assembled now, you will need to add a few otherwise unnecessary elbows to get it to connect. If you leave it that way add a clean out real close in case it clogs. More elbows equals easier clogs.

Comment: Thanks for the good information.  The basement was roughed in for a tub but I want to install a left drain shower alcove.  Isnt the pipe pictured above for the overflow?  I believe the bathroom is plumbed with the toilet and shower connected with a wye to the sewage ejector behind.  the sewage ejector has a vent pipe.   Is this correct and all I need is to install some elbows from the overflow drain?

Comment: I added a few more pictures to shower the tub rough-in placement and the sewage vent http://imgur.com/n0u4B5o   http://imgur.com/IwNKUy9  http://imgur.com/GmuZiYj

Comment: That pipe is not for the overflow. The overflow is part of the drain and a lot of the times has a drain lever involved with it. Left draining shower pans and left draining tubs are, for the most part the exact same thing for roughing in. The pipe extended above the floor is most likely there to mark the drain location, and is usually NOT glued in at this time. The vent for the toilet can be no farther than 5' from a vent, I do not know if the sewage ejector fits that need, but it may. You will or should redo the trap in the floor so it lines up with the drain in the shower pan.